# select rows with two commas in column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a pandas dataframe with column named "col" of str type. How can I select rows, where values in column "col" contains only two commas. I tryed `df[df['col'].count(',') == 2]`  but I recieve `'Requested level (,) does not match index name (None)'`. There are no NaN values in my column

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df[df['col'].str.count(',') == 2]
```